# Actual Running Thread In Java Visual VM

Tags: java, multithreading, jvisualvm

My Understanding from many articles that I have read regarding Multi-Threading is When One Thread is being executed, it will be handled by one available Logical Processor ( or Core). or 2 Threads per hyper-v logical processor.

But I'm getting confuse when I'm seeing Thread Tab in Java VisualVM that there are 21 Threads (User Created Thread) that are marked as "Running" at a time. as I only have 4 logical processors in My Laptop.

My processor is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz 2.50GHz which supports Hyper-Threading Technology, well it still only can process 8 Threads at a time.

[image]

How this can be happened ?

Please let me know if I have incorrect understanding.

Comment: You misunderstood. There may be hundreds of threads and the OS schedules the work of each thread to run for some nanoseconds on one core, then the next thread and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the information, at this context I mean is Java User Created Thread, Can it be recognized same as those hundreds of threads that you mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes. Any "Java User Created Thread" is actually created and scheduled by the OS when the Java process creates it.

Answer (score 2):

It just means the threads are running (as opposed to sleeping or waiting on something). It doesn't mean that all the threads are actually being executed at the same time, since you don't have that many cores. They all do compete for the time slices to get executed though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. appreciated it.

if there is reference for this, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

VisualVM only knows about the Threads from the view of the JVM, so any actual scheduling that the operating system does is not reflected. Having that many running threads simply means there are 21 threads that can be scheduled to immediately do work by the OS.

You can take a look at the javadocs for [`Thread.State`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) to see what the various states mean in terms of the JVM.

Comment: Your answer is same as @Kayaman Thanks anyway. appreciated it. if there is reference for this, please let me know

Comment: Added a link to `Thread.State`, which is used to show that specific graph.